# Clustering in MapKit with Swift

Tags: swift, mapkit

Is there in **Swift** the possibility to cluster markers in **MapKit**?
I know that it's possible in Google Maps SDK, but I can't find the same feature in MapKit.
I've found some libraries for Obj-C, but nothing for Swift

These some of the libraries that I have found:

- [FBAnnotationClustering](https://cocoapods.org/?q=on%3Aios%20cluster)
- [CCHMapClusterController](https://cocoapods.org/?q=on%3Aios%20cluster)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I translated FBAnnotationClustering to Swift:

https://github.com/ribl/FBAnnotationClusteringSwift

Works with `MapKit`.  It's a working sample project, and the readme  includes some integration and usage instructions.

There's also an associated blog post giving background on why we chose FBAnnotationClustering (I liked it), and why we translated it to Swift (didn't feel like troubleshooting Objective-C if we ran into issues later).

http://ribl.co/blog/2015/05/28/map-clustering-with-swift-how-we-implemented-it-into-the-ribl-ios-app/

Comment: Thanks this project is what I need!

Comment: thanks it is really helpful, but  I am looking for FBAnnotationClusteringSwift for swift 2

Comment: There is now clustering support in mapkit with iOS 11.

Comment: How to load geojson data for polylines with cluster?

Answer (score 5):

Use MKMarkerAnnotationViews for easy clustering. Here's an example of class I have, where you can set the clustering identifier.

Annotations with the same clustering identifier will automatically cluster.

```
class AnnotationView: MKMarkerAnnotationView {

    override init(annotation: MKAnnotation?, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)


        self.clusteringIdentifier = "AnnotationViewIdentifier"
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
}
```